# Process is terminating due to StackOverflowException on calling GetType()

Tags: c#, .net-core

I came across this by accident when forgetting a static modifier and have simplified it to a reproducible snippet. The following will fail with a StackOverflowException when ran:

```
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        Program program = new Program();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            var p = new Program();
            System.Console.WriteLine(p.GetType());
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this fail? Is it a bug or my misunderstanding of the CLR?

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance - the code you have is still not minimal to demonstrate the issue. Doing so would significantly improved the question (as you'd not really mention unrelated `.GetType` call) and possibly help you spot the issue yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it will recursively try to create new Program() objects until the stack overflows because of the lines:

```
class Program
{
    Program program = new Program();
```

You create a program, which then creates a program, which then creates a program ... etc to infinity.

I am unsure what you need to accomplish here but if you need to make an instance of a class within the same class I would assume you need to hit a base case eventually in order to stop the recursion.

Answer (score 3):

The offending line isn't `p.GetType()`, but the type initializer of `Program`.

When you create the program instance `var p = new Program();` it runs the initializer of `Program` to set up the new instance. That includes running any assignments to the fields of `Program`.

This initialized field is the culprit:

```
Program program = new Program();
```

To create an instance of `Program`, you must initialize the field `program` by creating a new instance of `Program`. This causes an infinite stack of initializers and generates your `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: Thanks, I see that now